# Using Xargs with hocr2pdf

Tags: shell-script, xargs

I'm trying to use tesseract and hocr2pdf on a series of .tif files in a folder.

Using `ls *.tif | xargs -I% tesseract % % -l fra hocr` produces the html files which have the same file name but with .html added. But `ls *.tif |xargs -I% hocr2pdf -i % -n -o %.pdf < %.html` is not working. I get the error message `%.html not found`. It seems xargs is having problems with the `<` in the hocr2pdf command.

How do I circumvent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

xargs isn't ideal for this task. You need a shell for redirection.

One option would be to invoke bash from xargs, but it's much simpler to use a for loop:

```
for f in ./*.tif; do
    tesseract "$f" "$f" -l fra hocr
    hocr2pdf -i "$f" -n -o "$f.pdf" < "$f.html"
done
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why `./*.tif` instead of `*.tif`?

Comment: If a filename starts with a hyphen-minus, it might get interpreted as a switch with argument. For example, the filename `-in.tif` would become `-i n.tif`. The leading `./` avoids this.

Comment: How do I make this recursive?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, [never parse the output of ls.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Now, the reason it's not working is that `xargs` does not see the `%.html`, bash does. The `<` is taken to be the end of the `xargs` command, therefore the substitution you have set up (`-I%`) no longer works. A better way to do what you want would be something like this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.tif" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' n; do 
    tesseract "$n" "$n" -l fra hocr &&
    hocr2pdf -i "$n.html" -n -o "$n.pdf"
done
```

Comment: No worries, haha. Minor obsession of mine, sorry. Beware that this is recursive, while the OP's `ls *.tif` is not.

Comment: True. All things considered, using a for loop as @Dennis [suggested](http://superuser.com/a/570376/151431) is better.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU Parallel you can get the processing parallelized:

```
parallel "tesseract {} {} -l fra hocr; hocr2pdf -i {} -n -o {}.pdf < {}.html" ::: *.tif
```

It takes literally 10 seconds to install GNU Parallel:

```
wget pi.dk/3 -qO - | sh -x
```

Watch the intro videos to learn more: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1